# Проблема с потоком android

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Есть следующий код:

```
package tanat.androidtesttask;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainList extends ListFragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    ArrayList data;
    DialogFragment dialogFragment;

    //подключаем мой фрагмент
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, null);

        dialogFragment = new MyDialog();

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.refresh);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "");

        final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                data = new MainActivity().demo();
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dialogFragment.dismiss();


        //      dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "");

 //       data = new MainActivity().demo();

        //создаем лист фрагментов
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    //вешаем слушатель на нажатие фрагмента
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        //передаем позицию елемента в второе активити
        //создаем интент
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainList.this.getContext(), InfoRoutActivity.class);
        //записываем в него ключ и позицию
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        //передаем
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    //свайп вниз для обновления
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // говорим о том, что собираемся начать
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Обновляем", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // начинаем показывать прогресс
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        // ждем 3 секунды и прячем прогресс
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                // говорим о том, что собираемся закончить
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"обновили", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

Это класс фрагмента. При его создании вызываться еще один фрагмент который представляет собой просто костомный DialogFragment вроде диалога прогреса.
а командой

```
data = new MainActivity().demo();
```

переходит в активити, из него в service и загружает json
затем ждем пока этот поток выполниться и закрываем диалог прогреса, а дальше создаем ListFragment из данных что скачали,
так по крайней мере задумано, НО
на этой самой команде выбивает следующую ошибку

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-130
                  Process: tanat.androidtesttask, PID: 1700
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                      at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                      at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                      at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:754)
                      at tanat.androidtesttask.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:0)
                      at tanat.androidtesttask.MainList$1.run(MainList.java:50)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

я уже пытался использывать Handler но не могу понять как правильно его использовать в данном случае, шарюсь в интернете уже 2 дня и безрезультатно.
Помогите пожалуйста
Зарание спасибо.

Comment: Эмм, вы создаёте новую Активити? И вызываете её метод? Про [активити](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html?hl=ru) и [фрагменты](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=ru). Вы не можете напрямую вызывать методы Активити. Handler - это своеобразный мост, по которому можно вести общение с потоком (Одностороннее).

Comment: Я видел на просторах что то типа
'public void run() {
Main.loadData(i);=
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);}'
И сам хандлер:
'private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_KEY); // удаляем диалог
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, AuthorsView.class);
            startActivity(intent);} };'
Я не создаю новое Активити я пытаюсь обратиться к начальному (а оно уже в класс service)

Comment: Нельзя напрямую обращаться к методам Activity (на самом деле можно, но **очень** не приветствуется). Я уже поделился ссылками на android developer. Вам следует прочесть документацию и просмотреть гайд от google на том же сайте. Слишком много рассказывать. Разве что про Handler. остальное сами по ссылкам.

Comment: нельзя создавать активити командой `new,` это системный компонент жизненного цикла, а не просто экземпляр класса в вакууме. точнее, создать можно, но работать ничего не будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Итак, `Handler` - это интерфейс для общения с потоком, к которому он приклеплен.
В качестве параметра он принимает поток, в котором будет работать (На самом деле специальный объект класса `Looper`, [документация по Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)). Вызов `Handle handler = new Handler() {...}` привязывает `Handler` к текущему потоку. Т.е. функции объекта будут выполнятся в его контексте создания. Это означает, что мы можем общаться с потоком посредством `Handler`.

Например:

```
HandlerThread getThread = new HandlerThread("getThread"); // Создали поток 
getThread.start(); // Запустили
getHandler = new Handler(getThread.getLooper()); // Получили объект Looper потока
getHandler.post(new Runnable() {...}); // Выдали код на исполнение потоку getThread
getHandler.obtainMessage(1, new SomeObject()); // Отослали сообщение с пользовательским типом и объект для обработки в параметре arg1.
```

Как видно из примера, мы создали новый поток (Заметьте, класс `HandlerThread` уже имеет `Looper`. Обычный `Thread` его иметь не будет и вам в ручную придется контролировать его время жизни), получили объект `Looper` и объявили `Handler`. Теперь мы можешь отправлять разные сообщение или отдать код для его исполнения в поток посредством вызова методов `getHandler`.

[Ссылка](http://startandroid.ru/ru/) на хороший туториал по Android для начинающих, официальный [гайд](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html?hl=ru) и настоятельно рекомендую прочитать мой комментарии выше и прочесть статьи по ссылкам.

Comment: Спасибо, проблему решил иначе но комментарии и ответ очень полезны. А startandroid - ом давно пользуюсь.